# How to use _printHierarchy in LLDB console with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, xcode6, lldb

Apple added a [private helper `_printHierarchy` in iOS8](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/a8f9f7eb4882c9dfc87166d876c547b75a24c5bb/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIViewController.h#L365) that can be used in LLDB console:

```
po [[[UIWindow keyWindow] rootViewController] _printHierarchy]
```

which prints out the whole view controller hierarchy in text form.

This works only if you are debugging code on Objective C. In Swift, however, this doesn't work:

```
(lldb) po [[[UIWindow keyWindow] rootViewController] _printHierarchy]
error: <EXPR>:1:13: error: expected ',' separator
[[[UIWindow keyWindow] rootViewController] _printHierarchy]
            ^
           ,
<EXPR>:1:24: error: expected ',' separator
[[[UIWindow keyWindow] rootViewController] _printHierarchy]
                       ^
                      ,
<EXPR>:1:44: error: expected ',' separator
[[[UIWindow keyWindow] rootViewController] _printHierarchy]
                                           ^
                                          ,
```

An equivalent usage in Swift doesn't work either:

```
po UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.rootViewController!._printHierarchy
```

ends up with an error (probably because `_printHierarchy` is a private property):

```
(lldb) po UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.rootViewController!._printHierarchy()
error: <EXPR>:1:64: error: 'UIViewController' does not have a member named '_printHierarchy'
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.rootViewController!._printHierarchy
                                                               ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

**The question is: How to print out the view controller hierarchy in Swift?** Or is there a way how to use ObjC in LLDB console even in Swift projects?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You point out how one shows the view controller hierarchy with:

```
po [[[UIWindow keyWindow] rootViewController] _printHierarchy]
```

You then say:

> This works only if you are debugging code on Objective C. In Swift, however, this doesn't work.

Actually, this depends a little upon how you pause the execution of your Swift program. The issue is that the `expression` command (which `po` uses) will use Swift expressions in Swift frames, and Objective-C expressions in Objective-C frames. Thus this means that the `po` behavior varies depending upon how the execution pauses:

- You can, for example, press the "pause" button while the app is running:

  [image: pause]

  If you do this, you will be able to use the above `po` syntax with the Objective-C expression without incident.
- If, on the other hand, you set a breakpoint inside your Swift code, you'll be in a Swift frame when you get to the `(lldb)` prompt. But you can explicitly tell the `expression` command that you want to use the Objective-C syntax with the `-l` (or `--language`) option:

  ```
  expr -l objc++ -O -- [[[UIWindow keyWindow] rootViewController] _printHierarchy]
  ```

This ability to specify the language in the `expr` command is discussed in WWDC 2014 video [Advanced Swift Debugging in LLDB](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?id=410).

Comment: Hmm, I've tried that and I updated my question with an error I get in console.

Comment: @TomKraina If you use a breakpoint in Swift code, you're in a Swift frame and thus `po` expects Swift expression. If, however, you just hit pause button while the Swift program is running (which is what I'm often doing), you will more than likely not be in a Swift frame when you get the `(lldb)` prompt, and thus the Objective-C expression is fine. Fortunately, if you pause the app in Swift frame, you can still explicitly provide `--language` option (or `-l` option) to specify that even if you're in Swift frame, that it should interpret Objective-C expression. See revised answer.

Comment: That's cool! I didn't know you can specify a language in `lldb`!

Comment: or just `expr -l objc++ -O -- [UIViewController _printHierarchy]`

Answer (score 13):

If you are stopped in Swift code, paste this line into the debugger console (after the `(lldb)` prompt) and press enter to print the hierarchy of the root view controller:

```
po UIWindow.value(forKeyPath: "keyWindow.rootViewController._printHierarchy")!
```

If you are stopped in Objective-C code or assembly code, use this line instead:

```
po [UIWindow valueForKeyPath:@"keyWindow.rootViewController._printHierarchy"]
```

Comment: Can you please add some context around your answer?

Comment: Why? The question was “How to use _printHierarchy in LLDB console with Swift?” and an answer is the command I showed.

Answer (score 2):

The options that have already been posted here are great, another option (similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37150773/902968)), if you absolutely need to be using the Swift lldb context (meaning you don't want to pass `-l objc`, is you can call `performSelector:`

Which is bridged to Swift like this:

```swift
func perform(_ aSelector: Selector!) -> Unmanaged<AnyObject>!
```

For this case you would call it like this:

```
po UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController!.perform("_printHierarchy")!.takeUnretainedValue()
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like, since this is a "private" helper, it is somehow not exposed to Swift. It is also not accessible from within Objective-C, i.e.

```
UIViewController* vc = // Assign view controller
[vc _printHierarchy];
```

results in a compile time error. However, what might work is using `NSSelectorFromString` inside a bridging header, e.g.

```
-(void) printHierarchyWithVC:(UIViewController*) vc
{
    [vc performSelector: NSSelectorFromString(@"_printHierarchy")];
}
```

Once this is defined, you can call `printHierarchyWithVC` from Swift.

Answer (score 1):

After some research, I found out that it's just a matter of exposing this particular API (copied from [iOS runtime headers](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/a8f9f7eb4882c9dfc87166d876c547b75a24c5bb/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIViewController.h#L365)) in project's bridging header so it becomes available to Swift:

```
@interface UIViewController (Debugging)
+ (id)_printHierarchy;
@end
```

During runtime, this class method can be called as follows:

```
(lldb) po UIViewController._printHierarchy() as NSString
<UINavigationController 0x7f8a50733c70>, state: appearing, view: <UILayoutContainerView 0x7f8a5064def0>
   | <MyApp.RootViewController 0x7f8a507341f0>, state: appearing, view: <UIView 0x7f8a5056d860> not in the window
```

...printing out the view controller hierarchy. Note that the method must be called only on the main (UI) thread.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using `expr -l objc++ -O -- [UIViewController _printHierarchy]` in the console as it will print out the full view hierarchy in text form, which I found significantly more useful than UIWindow.valueForKeyPath...  Note that you do not need to add `po` to print the hierarchy, just use as is.

This works for me, Xcode 8 / swift 3 though I think the same command also works in earlier versions of Xcode too because it looks like it is objective C.

example output from this command:

```
(lldb) expr -l objc++ -O -- [UIViewController _printHierarchy]

<MyProject.SwipeController 0x102213590>, state: disappeared, view: <UIView 0x102239ff0> not in the window
   + <MyProject.CameraViewController 0x102215680>, state: disappeared, view: <UIView 0x102422fd0> not in the window, presented with: <_UIFullscreenPresentationController 0x102219c60>
   |    + <MyProject.MapViewController 0x102214820>, state: appeared, view: <UIView 0x10bf52fe0>, presented with: <_UIFullscreenPresentationController 0x10fd1f890>
   |    |    | <MyProject.MapPlaceCollectionViewController 0x10bf54680>, state: appeared, view: <UICollectionViewControllerWrapperView 0x1022438d0>
```

Answer (score 1):

After installing [Chisel](https://github.com/facebook/chisel) you can simply do the following and [more](https://github.com/facebook/chisel#commands):

`(lldb) pvc`